# SharePoint 2010 MySites: Add a new tab to Current Navigation which acts like the Overview tab but points to a new aspx file

Tags: sharepoint-2010, navigation, master-pages

In SharePoint 2010 MySites, you can click on **"My Profile"** and you have 6 tabs, the first being **"Overview"**. It points to `person.aspx`. I would like to create another tab, **"Custom Tab"** and have it point to `customTab.aspx` but also perform like `person.aspx` in that it has the other user info at the top, the other tabs, and is a web part page. Does anyone have input on this?

As it stands right now, I can add tabs to the navigation with:

`Site Actions` -> `Site Settings` -> `Navigation` -> N`avigation Editing and Sorting`

But I dont know how to format the aspx page to act as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/11/customize-my-profile-tabs-for.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am still a little unclear now on how to create a new aspx page. If I copy person.aspx and rename and link to it, it doesnt act the same way. The tabs dont behave the same and I have a feeling it is due to the blurb at the top of the page which is in the tags: <% %>